# gremlin in AWS Glue with PySpark

Tags: python, graph, gremlin, aws-glue

I am trying to access gremlin via AWS Glue with PySpark as Runtime. As gremlinpython is external library, i had downloaded .whl file and placed in AWS S3. Now it was asking for "aenom" did the same. then isodate is required. So just wanted to know if there is anypackage which i can use instead of having separate modules.

Below is the sample script i am testing initially with all modules to keep it simple.

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
import site
import json
import pandas as pd
#from setuptools.command import easy_install
from importlib import reload
from io import StringIO
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
#dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)

#install_path = os.environ['GLUE_INSTALLATION']
#easy_install.main( ["--install-dir", install_path, "gremlinpython"] )

#(site)

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T, Column
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
```

required libraries are below, after that there is no error related to modules.

```
tornado-6.0.4-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
isodate-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
aenum-2.2.4-py3-none-any.whl
gremlinpython-3.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: are you sure `sudo pip install gremlinpython` only isnt sufficient, it was sufficient for me

Comment: I am on AWS Glue using PySpark Runtime environment. So i can't isntall package. I have to place packages somewhere and pass the location. Yes, gremlinpython package wasn't suffient.

Comment: do you have access to `sc` (spark context) ? if yes, does this runtime provide option to dp `sc.install_pypi_package("gremlinpython")`?

Comment: i have access to sc, But it never worked. 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'install_pypi_package'